# Finding the operating point of a transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt

I want to find the operating point of this circuit:

[image]

where we have an NPN transistor and \$R_V = 47\text{ k}\Omega\$, \$R_C = 1\text{ k}\Omega\$, \$R_E = 4,7\text{ k}\Omega\$, \$\beta = 100 \$,
\$+U_B = 10\text{ V}\$ and \$-U_B = -10\text{ V}\$.

My problem is, that I don't even know what the operating point really is.
In the exercise it says, that the operating point is the pair \$U_{CEA}\$,  and \$I_{CA}\$. But there is no letter A in the circuit shown.

So what is the operating point in general, and how would I go about finding it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The A probably means 'Absent of any other input'. What you have to find is the Uce, the voltage collector to emitter, and Ic, the collector current. Taken as a pair, they give you the operating point of the transistor.

Let's assume you have sufficient notes on transistors to take the thinnest of hints.

Start by assuming infinite current gain beta, so no base current. Work out what voltages you can, then currents, then more voltages. That gives you a rough cut at the answer.

Now assume finite gain, and work it out properly. Make sure it's fairly close to your rough cut, to check for correctness.

Comment: While that's probably what I would do (iterative approach) the prof may want him or her to write equations and solve them for full marks.

Comment: Do you assume +/-UB is referenced with respect to GND (i.e. the input node potential)?

Comment: Hey thank you very much. So, if I want to find I_C, I would try to find the base current I_B with KVL. With  \beta, I could then find I_C. For U_{CE}, I would use KVL again on the second loop (with RC and UB). Is +UB and -UB together the same as a 20V voltage source?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it's much easier to check your equations if you know roughly what they ought to produce, that's what the 'do it properly' 2nd step is.

Comment: I'll give you the infinite beta case, so you can see what the real answer is close to. Base current is zero, so vb=0. VE = -0.7v (looks like to have to assume that, not given), so you know drop across Re, which gives you Ie, which gives you Ic, which gives you Vc. As beta drops from infinity, you get some base current, and Vb and Ve drop. You do the sums properly.

Comment: Ah ok I see. But where would the base current come from, in the case beta not infinite? Normally there would be a voltage source next to RV but now there is a grounding symbol. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: A ground terminal is just a terminal, as well as being the zero volt reference for measuring voltages. Base current flows from the ground, through RV, to the base at (maybe) -0.3v, to the emitter at (maybe) -1.0v, through Re, to the power supply at -UB. Or you could describe it as the -Ub terminal dragging current out of the ground terminal through the base, and the +Ub terminal through the collector. Your power supply has three terminals, +10v, 0 and -10v, and all are low impedance.

Comment: So is this the same as having two loops, with one having a voltage source of 10V and the other having -10V? (forgot to mention that we should assume V_EB = 0,7V)

Comment: I'm not going to advise you where your loops should be drawn, I can't be bothered with all that KVL stuff, you've already had the the full extent of my analysis (infinite beta, rarely more than 1% wrong). From what I understand, as long as you're consistent, it all comes out in the wash. However, choosing the right loops to start with can simplify your equations. As an exercise, you might want to try calling -Ub 0v, the Rv terminal +10v, and the +Ub terminal +20v. It's exactly the same electrically, but it might be easier to get your head around. Assign them back again at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The operating point also called quiescent point is the voltage at some point in the circuit and the current flowing through the circuit when the input signal is zero.

In your example I assume the requested quiescent current and voltage are the output voltage and collector current.

Answer (score 0):

The operating point is the solution of the circuit considering DC voltages and DC currents. No AC component at the input need be considered.

So your job is to figure out what currents flow where considering the values of the supply voltages and resistors. At some point in the calculations you will have to use every piece of the constants data provided.